# how to customize addressbook UI of iPhone

Tags: iphone, addressbook, viber

I want to customize my addressbook UI,like:
adding some marks on the right of tableview's cell in "All Contacts" page, and adding sth in the detail page.

Just Like Vibro:
[image]

[image]

1 how to add "Viber" mask on the right:Can I get the original tableview, and add my mask to each cell.
2 how to add "viber" label in the detail page

Now, I get the metadata from addressbook and draw the UI myself.
I find it is difficult.
I want to know if I can reuse the addressbook UI provided by iPhone and add my UI.

thanks.

Comment: I fulfill it although not in a elegant way.  So I appreciate every helpful answer.

Comment: Can you please share the technique you used, even if it's not elegant? It might be the only way! Thanks.